# TryUpdateModel validating fields not in the includeProperties

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I am trying to save a couple of fields in the database in the MVC controller with the TryUpdateModel.  However, it keeps returning false because it's validating on the email address and phone number saying invalid format.  There fields are blank or empty.  On the TryUpdateModel method, I specified what fields are included and these fields aren't one of them.  I am not sure why it's validating outside of the included properties?

```
Guid EmailGuid = new Guid(emailguidparam);
MyModelobject MyList= db.MyLists.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ReceiptGuid == EmailGuid);


var currentUsername = User.Identity.Name != null
                ? User.Identity.Name
                : "Anonymous";
MyList.Field1= true;
MyList.Field2= currentUsername;
MyList.Field3= DateTime.Now;

 success = TryUpdateModel(MyList, includeProperties: new string[] { "field1", "field2", "field3" });
       if(success){
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("AnotherActionController", new { success = false, message = "Thanks." });
       }
```

success is always false because it's validating other fields besides what I specified.  Anyone know how to fix this or why it's validating other fields?

Comment: `includeProperties` means it will only set the value of the properties that are in the list. The fact you might have a (say) `[Required]` attribute on another property still means that the model will be invalid. You should be using a view model with only the properties you need, then in POST method, get the data model then map the view model properties to the data model before saving the data model.

Comment: This is sort of a confirmation link that a user would click to confirm a user received an email.  Is there a safer method to do this? @StephenMuecke

Comment: You will need to show your model (including validation attributes) for `MyModelobject` (not clear at the moment what property is causing `ModelState` to be invalid)

Comment: The phone and email fields are not valid because it's validating an empty string.  Is there a better method than what I tried up above?  I think there is a  ModelState.Remove() to take out the offending fields?  Is that even recommended? @StephenMuecke

Comment: That wont help because you only call that after `TryUpdateModel()` to remove `ModelState` errors (by that time the value of `success` is already `false`). But why just include those properties in the `includeProperties` list?

Comment: The user click on the link from an email, and I just want to update those field to indicate the user acknowledged the email.  I rather not have the user go to a page, then click on another button to do a post.... As the code stands, if I add in the "test@email" or (555) 333-3333 in the fields it's complaining about; it saves it fine.

Comment: But does `db.MyLists.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ReceiptGuid == EmailGuid);` not return a `MyModelobject` that contains the phone and email properties? (still a little unsure of exactly what your needing to do)

Comment: I just want to update a few fields using a get method when a user click a link containing the guid, sort of like the account creation link.  That's all.  yes, it does return the phone and email properties.  But like when filling a form, it should only validate if there are actual content.  Why does the model validate on the empty string?

Comment: Because you must have a validation attribute on those properties (for example a `[Required]` attribute (you have not posted the model so can't be sure). Why not just remove the `includeProperties` list. The values have not been changed so they wont be change in the database when you save the model.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out what went wrong in my scenario, beside a lack of a complete understand of how MVC and entity framework.  The fields it's validating had an empty string.  Even though, the string is empty; it still gets validated.  In order not to have the model validate these strings (a valid phone and/or email address), the strings need to be NULL.  Before calling TryUpdateModel, I checked the fields for String.Empty then set it to NULL.  Part of the issue was the table the model pulls from gets populated by a sql stored procedure.  So the data was outside the scope of the MVC when it was written.

The lesson 101 here for me is the model validates on empty strings.